# How to give three letters individual tasks

Tags: python-3.x

```
import random

print('please enter one of three letters\n E for easy\n N for normal\n H for hard')    
difficulty = input()
if input().upper().startswith('E'):
    print('E was selected')
elif input().upper().startswith('N'):
    print('N was selected')
elif input().upper().startswith('H'):
    print('H was selected')
else:
    print('please enter E,N or H)
```

i want the user to be able to enter E,N or H and then for it to print what they have selected after.

Answer (score 1):

```
difficulty = input('please enter one of three letters\n E for easy\n N for normal\n H for hard')

if (difficulty.upper() == 'E'):
    # Do "E" things
    print('E was selected')
elif (difficulty.upper() == 'N'):
    # Do "N" things
    print('N was selected')
elif (difficulty.upper() == 'H'):
    # Do "H" things
    print('H was selected')
else:
    print('please enter E,N or H')
```

REPL: http://repl.it/1J4/1

Comment: +1. The good: You identified the problem by doing `difficulty.upper()` instead of `input().upper()`. The bad: In Python 3 `raw_input()` is renamed to `input()`. The ugly: it's Friday and we're on StackOverflow.

Comment: Huh, interesting. Thank you. Not too familiar with 3.x